# How to set cron PATH globally (i.e. for all users) permanently?

Tags: path, cron

We need to have /usr/local/bin in cron's path for all users. Is there a way to set it system-wide, without needing to edit each individual user's crontab?

We've tried adding PATH to /etc/crontab:

```
# grep PATH /etc/crontab
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

But when users have this in their crontab:

```
$ crontab -l | grep PATH
* * * * * echo $PATH > /tmp/current_cron_path
```

...it reveals that their path is still set to default:

```
$ cat /tmp/current_cron_path
/usr/bin:/bin
```

Comment: General hint: Writing "it didn't work" will not usually get you a useful reply. Always describe *how exactly* it didn't work, that is, exactly what did you do, and what exactly was the result.

Comment: Please note that [relying on `echo` in your cron is possibly unreliable](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149504/how-can-i-tell-if-my-hourly-cron-job-has-run).

Answer (score 5):

You can configure your PATH in crontab configuration file [as shown in the first code except there](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-7.2-Manual/custom-guide/cron-task.html). First specify the env variables, then specify jobs.

UPD: Due to fact that link is broken, here's an excerpt:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Comment: does not work on ubuntu, even after restarting cron

Comment: @grosser: Well, it should. Please post your complete crontab (edit your answer), along with the output it produces and why you believe it does not work. Then we'll see...

Comment: Also note that the format of the VARIABLE=value lines is somewhat more restricted than in a shell script: Each assignment must be on a line of its own, and you may not use variables on the right-hand-side (e.g. PATH=$PATH:/bla will not work).

Comment: i updated the question, setting the PATH in an individual crontab  did work, just the global change did not work

Comment: Try specifying PATH variables in each crontab where you need it. Probably it's done due to security issues.

BTW, in ubuntu (I've checked) PATH is defined in /etc/crontab and /etc/cron.d/anacron in ubuntu. So it seems that it is not being inherited from /etc/crontab. Just try defining it in root's crontab (`sudo crontab -e`)

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the PATH variable should work in Ubuntu, how do you say it is not working ?

Refer #14: [Linux Crontab: 15 Awesome Cron Job Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)

Comment: i updated the question, setting the PATH in an individual crontab  did work, just the global change did not work

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a solution for this either. The closest I got to a decent solution is the following (taken from https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Better_cron_env_and_shell_control_with_the_SHELL_variale.html).

- Change the shell for your cron job and point it to a bash script. I.e., at the top of the cronjob, add:
  `SHELL=/path/to/setup/cron.bash`
- In this shell script, load environment variables and specify other vars. Make sure to include the following 4 lines at the top. It resets the SHELL variable to bash, and executes a bash shell to run the cronjobs.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

source /etc/environment
source /etc/profile
# restore SHELL env var for cron
SHELL=/bin/bash

# execute the cron command in an actual shell
exec /bin/bash --norc "$@"
```

Downside: this requires you to specify the `SHELL=...` at the top of every cronjob. Upside: you'll be using regular environment variables, and you won't have to worry about keeping variables consistent between cron and others

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to be root, can you try editing `/etc/init.d/cron` and changing the PATH there?
I haven't tested this, but would be interesting to check.

Comment: did not seem to work, i just added PATH=xxx into /etc/init.d/cron but the * * * * * echo $PATH output was the same