# ip does not work / does not produce output when run with cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a bash script in which I use the `ip r` command. When I run the script in bash it works but when cron runs it it does not.

This is the line in my script:

```
ping -q -w 1 -c 1 `ip r | grep -m 1 default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` >/dev/null || exit
```

To test that the `ip r` command is the problem I added `notify-send "TEST $(ip r)"` in front of that line. When I execute the script in bash it sends the notification with TEST and the output of `ip r` but when run with cron the notification only contains `TEST`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `whereis ip` gives `ip: /usr/sbin/ip /usr/share/man/man8/ip.8.gz`. How do I find out what $PATH it is? Running `echo $PATH` in bash prints `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/alex/.local/bin`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski You were right, it was a problem with $PATH. I now added ` eval "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin    :/usr/sbin:/home/alex/.local/bin"` at the beginning of my `crontab -e` command and now the `ip r` works in cron as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$PATH` variable was not set when run with cron. So I ran `echo $PATH` in bash and then set the `$PATH` variable to that output in the crontab command.

For that I added

```
eval "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin :/usr/sbin:/home/alex/.local/bin"
```

in `crontab -e` where everything after `PATH=` is the output of the command `echo $PATH` when run in bash.

Comment: Cumbersome, I think. Please see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/164404/432690). A line starting with `PATH=` should do.